# Assembler i8080 print result in decimal format

Tags: assembly, intel-8080

I need to write number of words that doesn't have (+,-,*,/) inside. The result must be given in dec. form like 04, 00, 15 etc. I have number of words inside the e. If the number of words is less than 10 it's correct like 09 but when the count is 10 i get 1:. I understand what's going on so the ascii value goes on so i need to be reset to 0 after the number on left is raised.

Here is my code where i want to write things. I use emustudio:

```
 update_counters:
        lxi h,text2      
        call putstr

        mov a,e          

        
        mvi c,0          
divide_by_10:
        sui 10           
        jnc increment_c  
        adi 10           
        jmp proceed_to_print 
increment_c:
        inr c            
        jmp divide_by_10

proceed_to_print:
        ; Vypíš desiatky
        mov a,c
        adi '0'          
        call putchar     
        
        ; Vypíš jednotky
        mov a,e          
        ani 0Fh         
        adi '0'          
        call putchar     

        call newline     
        hlt
```

I tried to reset a number on right but i don't know how and i run out of ideas.

Comment: Using `ani 0Fh` you keep the 4 lowest bits. That won't work for decimal. You need the remainder. Luckily you already calculated that in the loop, you just need to preserve that while you print the first digit. For example, at `proceed_to_print` do `mov e,a` and delete the `ani 0Fh` (although that will be harmless).